# My method can't be called

Tags: java, class, methods

I have been trying for hours at using methods in java but I have yet to figure it out. Whenever I call my method, it throws an error. And whenever I don't call it, it returns nothing (expected).

```
public class javaAttempt {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      char[] helloArray = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
      String helloString = new String(helloArray);  
      System.out.println( helloString );
   }
   javaAttempt.main();
}

Error: javaAttempt.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
   javaAttempt.main();
```

Please help because I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't need to call a method called `main` - it gets called automatically when you run your Java program.  So you should remove the line that says `javaAttempt.main()`.

Comment: Terminology: compile errors aren’t *thrown* like exceptions are.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem still, nothing is returned. It is supposed to say hello but nothing is returned currently.

Comment: I presume you mean "nothing is printed" - since "returned" has a particular meaning in Java.  How are you compiling it and running it?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes, nothing is printed, and I am running it by "javac javaAttempt.java" in the terminal on mac

Comment: No, that's not _running_ it, that's just _compiling_ it.  You'll still need to _run_ it, with a command like `java javaAttempt`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem oh my god your right!, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to rename your file and class to capitalise the J in java:

JavaAttempt.java

You don't 'call' the main method, that is done for you when you run the class using

`java JavaAttempt`

```
public class JavaAttempt {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      char[] helloArray = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
      String helloString = new String(helloArray);
      System.out.println( helloString );
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use capital letters for class names, provided the class name matches the file name, and matches how you call it.  It's still good to follow the standard convention though.

Comment: Yes, but its good practice and to run the code sample provided you'll have to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other methods as shown below.

```
   public class javaAttempt {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      char[] helloArray = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.' };
      String helloString = new String(helloArray);  
      System.out.println( helloString );

      othermethod();
      javaAttempt obj = new javaAttempt();
      obj.anothermethod();

   }

   //static method
   public static void othermethod(){
       System.out.println( "inside othermethod." );
   }

   public static void anothermethod(){
       System.out.println( "inside anothermethod." );
   }
}
```